# Exchange Arrows in bmatrix

Tags: matrices

How can I add exchange arrows in this matrix?

Here is a pic to show what I want to achieve

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\[
\mbox{
\Large$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &2\\
1&1&3\\
2&1&4
\end{bmatrix}
$}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy solution with `pstricks`: the relevant entries in the matrix are `\rnode`s and linked through a node connection (`\ncarc`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{6pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\mbox{
\Large$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rnode{a}{1} &\rnode{b}{2}\\
\rnode{c}{1}&1&\rnode{d}{3}\\
\rnode{e}{2}&\rnode{f}{1}&4
\end{bmatrix}
$}
\psset{arrows=<->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesepA=1pt, nodesepB=0pt, arcangle=30}
\ncarc[linecolor=Gold]{c}{a}\ncarc[linecolor=Crimson]{e}{b}\ncarc[linecolor=Brown]{f}{d}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `l.484 \ncarc[linecolor=Gold]{c}{a}
                                  \ncarc[linecolor=Crimson]{e}{b}\ncarc[line...
`   There is an error message

Comment: How did you compile? Try with `xelatex`.

Comment: I choose `pdflatex`

Comment: Can you fix this without changing `pdflatex`?

Comment: The problem is that pdftex does not have the computing capabilities required by postscript. So you may either follow the traditional way: latex+dvips+pstopdf, or load the `auto-pst-pdf` package after `pstricks` and compile with the switch `-shell-escape` or compile with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 5):

One possibilities is use of the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}       % new

\begin{document}
{\Large
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tikzmarknode{a1}{1} & \tikzmarknode{b1}{2}\\
\tikzmarknode{a2}{1}     & 1    &\tikzmarknode{c1}{3}\\
\tikzmarknode{b2}{2}     & \tikzmarknode{c2}{1} &   4
\end{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, 
                        >={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 2]}
                        ]
\draw[<->, thick, red, semitransparent]  
        (a1) edge (a2) 
        (b1) edge (b2)
        (c1)  to  (c2);
\draw[<->, thick, blue, semitransparent]
        (a1) edge[bend right] (a2)
        (b1) edge[bend right] (b2)
        (c1)  to[bend right]  (c2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to select `\draw[...]` which you more prefer (for red or for blue) arrows and remove other.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nicematrix` which will create a PGF/Tikz node under each cell of the matrix. Then, you have to draw the arrows with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=A,columns-width=7mm]
1 & 1 & 2 \\[1ex]
1 & 1 & 3 \\[1ex]
2 & 1 & 4 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
  every path/.style = { <->, thick, blue , bend right = 15, } ]
\draw (A-1-2) to (A-2-1) ;
\draw (A-2-3) to (A-3-2) ;
\draw (A-1-3) to (A-3-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above]

Comment: There is a problem with this. The blue lines don't have starting arrow

Comment: After compileing your code twice. it finally worked as I expected. Can you move matrix to the center? This is too left

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. If you want to center the matrix, you can put it between `\[`and `\]` instead of `$` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks. your method works great. Is there any way to enlarge this matrix? btw, it's too small

Comment: You can set the width of the columns with the option `columns-width` in the environment `{bNiceMatrix}`. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe as a TikZ-matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
BendArrow/.style={<->, thick, red, rounded corners=3pt},
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={inner sep=0pt,  
}, 
column sep=1.5em, row sep=1.5em, 
left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}
]{
1  &  1 & 2             \\
1  &  1 & 3             \\
2  &  1 & 4             \\
};

\foreach \Start/\End in {1-2/2-1, 1-3/3-1, 2-3/3-2}{
\draw[BendArrow] (m-\Start.west) --  ([xshift=-0.5em]m-\Start.west)  -- ([xshift=-0.75em]m-\End.west) -- (m-\End.west);
}

% Another method:
%\draw[BendArrow] (m-1-2.west) to[bend right=90] (m-2-1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one +1 ... :-)